# How can I create and compile only one class for import within other project in android

Tags: android

How can I create and compile only one class for import within another project? For example, the `View` class, `Bundle` class, `Activity` class etc. are made already and we can use them in each project.

Is it possible to create a custom class and use it in other projects in Sndroid Studio? If the answer is yes, please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a submodule.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/sdk/installing/create-project.html#CreatingAModule) is how to create a module in `Android Studio`.

Follow the guild to [reference a library module part](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/sdk/installing/create-project.html#ReferencingLibraryModule).

If you wanna the submodule in other projects, just copy/paste the whole folder into another project. Or, make it a [gradle library](https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/), then just add `compile 'com.xxx.yyy:zzz:1.0.0'` to your `build.grale` file. Good luck.